# Where is GCC package on Debian experimental?

Tags: gcc, package, debian, toolchain

The Debian experimental link has multiple packages for a large number of software artifacts

https://packages.debian.org/experimental/

However, there is no GCC package under the 'Development' section or on a section by itself.

What is the location of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) ?

Comment: Why do you think gcc should be there?

Comment: that's the correct location for an experimental build of gcc, may be gcc 14. Why do you ask ?

Answer (score 1):

The experimental repository contains packages that are still being developed and are probably going to have malfunctions. It says as much here: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental

Also from that link, Experimental is just an extension of Unstable or `sid` and isn't a complete distro. If you look under the Development packages for `sid`, then you'll see `gcc`, `g++`, `libstdc++`, `libgfortran` and other compiler tools. They aren't under experimental because it's not a complete distro and is meant to be used with `sid` which already has them.